# Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, darknet

I am trying to do object detection using YOLO from the official website:https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/
But I cannot integrate OpenCV with it though I have already install OpenCV in my both python version python and python3
her is the error:

```
rajan@RGR:~/darknet$ ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights videosample.mp4
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

so can anyone help me to solve this, I have been trying to solve it for more than a week but I could not do it. I would be glad if someone gives me the solution. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi. You should opencv =1 in makefile, and make again**

if you want to test on a video then type

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/obj.data cfg/yolo-tiny-obj.cfg
backup/yolo-tiny-obj_40000.weights data/test.mp4
```

**or you can upgrade your openc**v

Comment: I did exactly this, cmake-gui says: Found OpenCV: C:/Users/SampleUser/.conda/envs/tf_gpu/Library (found version "3.4.2"). Executed again AlexeyAB's instructions for Windows installation, tried running the command again, same error again. :(

Comment: By make you meant to write ` .\build.ps1` on darknet repo folder - right ? I did this. But still same error